# Modular UV unwrapping and texturing curved areas

Tags: mesh, texturing, uv

So I'm trying to make these modular road tiles (5pcs) and decided to do a quick build to see how well everything fits and to test out some texturing. The end result is trying to become a bit stylized/cartoony feel.

I've now hit a tiny roadblock as the corner pieces are curved and not straight in the uv's. I can't seem to find a way to unwrap the model for the Light grey areas to be straight and use a single texture image for it.

The straighten uv button (or plugin, can't remember which ones those are) isn't really straightening anything but making the uv islands more crooked and not eliminating the curve completely.

Do I need to just bite the bullet and make separate textures for all curved areas or is there a way to unwrap the islands straight?

Any tips are welcome too. First time trying to do anything modular.

Thanks in advance.

Using blender 2.79b

[image: Trying to come up with a way to straighten uv's for texturing]

Comment: Have you tried using Follow Active Quads?

Comment: Yes I did try that but the desired effect was not achieved. It becomes more of a trapezoid. I could select all the edges from the uv and manually straighten all,  but that seems more time consuming than helpful.  [link](https://imgur.com/a/PdGpbSA) Heres the outcome of following active quads with both length and even.

Comment: In certain conditions techniques which help: select one or 2 of the edge loops on the UV map which should be straight, align them with W > Align Auto (or X / Y) and pin the vertices. Then unwrap once again, the rest of the island will stick to pinned vertices. Another technique is UV Squares addon, it should deal with this (choose To Grid By Shape). One more is Follow Active Quads, make sure to unwrap one face and make it square, *then* select the rest of the mesh and run the operator.

Comment: You might try out [renderhjs' TexTools for Blender](https://renderhjs.net/textools/blender/) It has (among many other very useful UV tools) a Rectify function that's definitely capable of straightening UVs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You might try out renderhjs' TexTools for Blender It has (among many other very useful UV tools) a Rectify function that's definitely capable of straightening UVs. – metaphor_set

This ended up being the method I now used. I wonder why I haven't stumbled upon this addon sooner?

Thank you for sharing this! I'm sure I'm going to get more out of this addon in the future!

Answer (score 0):

Weeell, this isn't my place of expertise, but it'd suggest minding where you place your seams.

and yes, Separating the mesh into bits is also not entirely out of the question

From the looks of things you need to find some way to move the texture about. I suggest finding Darrin Lyle's UV mapping Tutorials on YouTube, they're invaluable for stuff like this. it looks cool too, lemme know when you've gotten around this.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I have to take a look at Darrin's tutorials to see if that might help. The tiles are mostly separate, I've only ALT-D'ed the tiles to do a "quick" mockup and do fixes to the uv's if I see some problem areas - like what I'm trying to do now. In the end I'm going to put all these to unity and create it again there. Like I said, I really only have 5 pieces to work with that i've just moved around to see how it looks like. 

In the end I might just do it manually if I can't find something that might help with this.